# Searching for a variable string from a file with grep

Tags: grep

I tried now for a while to

- read from a file test.txt (which has two lines "aaaa" and "bbbb")
- take these lines to search the strings within a folder and its subfolders

My solution looks like this:

```
while read line 
do echo $line
    grep -irl $line /home 2>/dev/null
done < test.txt
```

If I replace `$line` with `aaaa` it finds the files where `aaaa` is written in, with `$line` it doesn't work...?

Maybe you have an idea?

Comment: Could it be that `test.txt` has Windows/DOS line endings? Does it work after you run `dos2unix test.txt`?

Comment: Have you try to quote `$line` in `grep`?

Comment: I already tried the quotes and I wrote the file on UNIX. But I found now out that it could be a problem with the interpretation of /home after $line - because if I change to /home and locate the files in there anything works fine...?!
So it seems a bit that if I use $line it does not interprete the path after as a path...

Comment: I would still think `$line` contains something you don't expect, but maybe I'm wrong. You could do an `echo "$line" | xxd` and compare the output.

Comment: A couple of things you could try:
1. Try directly on a file you know has aaaa. E.g. grep -irl $line /home/path/to/file
2. Try removing some of the grep switches in #1 above
3. Make sure you don't have hidden characters in the file
while read line ; do echo X"$line"X; done < test.txt

Comment: Hm. Seems you were right with the formats. As I re-wrote the file with VI anything worked fine - thanks a lot :-) !!

Comment: This is what the `-f` option is for: `grep -irl -f test.txt dir`

Answer (score 2):

The `grep` utility has a `-f` option whose argument is the name of a file. `-f` tells `grep` to read patterns from the specified file and then search for all of them, just as if those patterns had been individually specified on the command line. It combines with other options like `-r`.

`-f` is specified by POSIX.

GNU Grep allows the file to be specified as `-`, so the patterns are read from standard input; POSIX says that only *file* arguments may be specified as `-` for standard input; no such thing is required for *pattern_file* arguments.

If the lines of the search file are meant to be strings to look for in the input, as opposed to regular expressions, add the `-F` option (for fixed-string).

Comment: ... and if you want to match complete lines (not partial lines), also add `-x`.

Comment: The edits and comment above are superfluous to my original remark that "[i]t combines with other options".  The patterns coming from `-f` behave like patterns from the command line.